# angularjs scope doesn't apply to template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
myApp.controller('employersController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    api.runAjax("getUser", {
            method: "GET"
        }).done(function (result) {
            $scope.employers = result;
        });
}]);
```

and in my template I use {{employers}} with ng-repeat I see nothing. I suspect the $scope doesn't apply because the the ajax call isn't using $q or $resource. When I console $scope.employers, I did see my array.

Comment: Did you check if the request returns data? Can you provide a fiddler or plunkr for more details?

Comment: Have you tried `$scope.$apply();`?

Comment: why mixup the jQuery with angular..use `$http` service to make ajax..It would be in angular context..no need to worry about the digest cycle..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not using the angular `$http` service, you should use [`$scope.$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) to manually update bindings.

```
api.runAjax("getUser", {
        method: "GET"
    }).done(function (result) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.employers = result;
        });


    });
```